# PHP The reason of make an get_instance method in a class

Tags: php, class, oop, instance

I have a little question, I think it is a stupid question.
I'm starting to coding OOP and I saw a lot of classes on the internet that had this piece of code:

```
public static $istance;
public function __construct(){
  //some code...
  $this->instance = $this;
}
public function get_instance(){
  return $this->instance;
}
```

My question is: what is the reason?

Comment: i feel it resembles a pattern a design pattern

Comment: The main reason for this code is shoe-horning of global state in object oriented programming tools.  This is why singleton is a known **anti-pattern**. Please, don't use it. **EVER**.

Answer (score 5):

This is the bad realisation of singleton http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern.

Shortly: **Singleton** is design pattern, which guarantees that the single-threaded application will be the only instance of the class with a global access point.

Right realisation

```
 class Singleton {
     protected static $instance;
     private function __construct(){ /* ... @return Singleton */ }
     private function __clone()    { /* ... @return Singleton */ } 
     private function __wakeup()   { /* ... @return Singleton */ }  
     public static function getInstance()  {
         if ( !isset(self::$instance) ) {
             self::$instance = new self();
         }
         return self::$instance;
     }
     public function doAction() { /* ... */ }
  }
```

Call instance

```
  Singleton::getInstance()->doAction();
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the context of the code snippet you provided is not distinctively clear to me, it looks like they're implementing a **singleton pattern** in that piece of code.

If you'd like to know more about the **singleton pattern** generally, check it out [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Sample [implementation of **singleton pattern** in PHP](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html) can be found here.

What is the essence of this pattern?

> **When designing web applications, it often makes sense conceptually and architecturally to allow access to one and only one instance of a particular class. The singleton pattern enables us to do this.**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). It ensure we'll have only one instance of the class.

However, in general the constructor is `private`, to prevent clients to create new instances themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are getting at here is the singleton pattern. The "some code" part of your example would check first for a presence of an existing class having been already instantiated. what code would go in get instance would be a check for the class first in the construct.

```
    if ($this->instance === null) {
        $this->instance = new YourClass();
    }
    return $inst;
```

This pattern has been widely overused, but it is useful for database connections, for instance, where you would only want one instance of the connection floating around at a time. Contrast this to Factory pattern where multiple objects can be spawned.